# Using Piecewise functions for LTSpice behavioural voltages

Tags: sensor, spice

I'm currently designing an analog signal conditioning circuitry for a sensor in SPICE, but I have little time so instead of creating a macro model for that sensor, I will be using behavioral voltages to mimic the sensor voltage output for that sensor. The only problem is, the calibration curves that I have are two equations (for two different sensing ranges) and I need them combined as one behavioral voltage, which means I'll need to input a piece-wise function.

Comment: You have a very large discontinuity in there, what will you do if `Vref` goes out of bounds? The 1st eq. has `~0.98` for `rho=3`, while the 2nd has `~0.47`.

Comment: Hmmmm, that I did not take into consideration. Thanks for pointing it out!!

Comment: Please don't edit your question after it has been answered and the answer accepted because that can make the answer useless. Besides, people in the future, searching for similar problems, will see a question with an accepted answer (and upvoted) that does not match the question, which can be confusing.

Comment: I temporarily removed the graph, since my colleague (whom I took the graph from) told me to not upload his image and I should construct my own. I will be uploading a version of the graph that I've made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this page as a reference for the behavioral sources: http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29

Anyway, you can set up your equation like this:

V=(EQ1)*(V(test)>X) + (EQ2)*(V(test)<=X)

Where:

EQ1 - First equation

EQ2 - Second equation

test - Node from which you determine the testing range

X - the value you want to split the equations at

The '>' and '<=' parts of the function will return 1 if true, and 0 if false.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the reference, and telling me how to do so at the same time. I hope you have a good day

Comment: Any time! Hope you have a good day as well, good luck with your design.